# Loading background image with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, background

I want to load (asynchroon) a background image by means of jquery. I don't want it to stretch or resize on reload. Just position it on the bottom right of the body. Maybe nice to load and fade it in.
Anyone familiar with that?

Comment: why do you want to load it async ,any reason?? you can have the html ready and use jquery to show.

Comment: I don't want the rendering and displaying of the page to wait for the image to be loaded or vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like `$('#my_selector').css('background', 'url(path/to/image) bottom right');`